# Producing SVG output

Tags: tikz-pgf, dvisvgm

I have been using LaTeX, Ti*k*Z and MiKTeX on Windows 10 Pro since 2015 to successfully produce PDF files.

The current version of the **Ti*k*Z manual 3.1.9a** has a simple example in section **10.2.4 Producing SVG Output** (on page **121**) that doesn't work for me.

Simply create a TeX file (as in the manual) containing:

```
% example.tex
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Hello \tikz [baseline] \fill [fill=blue!80!black] (0,.75ex) circle[radius=.75ex];
\end{document}
```

And then run:

```
latex example
dvisvgm example
```

`latex example` creates the files: example.aux, example.dvi and example.log which appear to be okay.

`dvisvgm example` reports the following error:

```
D:\_DEVelopment\z_svg1>dvisvgm example
pre-processing DVI file (format version 2)
processing page 1
  ERROR: error in special: '>' or '/>' expected at end of opening tag <g
  ERROR: error in special: '>' or '/>' expected at end of opening tag <g
  ERROR: error in special: '>' or '/>' expected at end of opening tag <g
  ERROR: error in special: '>' or '/>' expected at end of opening tag <g
  ERROR: error in special: '>' or '/>' expected at end of opening tag <g
  ERROR: error in special: '>' or '/>' expected at end of opening tag <g
  ERROR: error in special: '>' or '/>' expected at end of opening tag <g
  ERROR: error in special: '>' or '/>' expected at end of opening tag <g
  ERROR: error in special: '>' or '/>' expected at end of opening tag <g
  ERROR: error in special: '>' or '/>' expected at end of opening tag <g
  graphic size: 32.291705pt x 6.944447pt (11.349236mm x 2.440694mm)
  output written to example.svg
1 of 1 page converted in 0.0900002 seconds
```

Trying the preferred commands below also give me the same error:

```
lualatex --output-format=dvi example
dvisvgm example
```

So I guess the .dvi file is created incorrectly. And idea why?

**UPDATE:**
I upgraded MiKTeX to 21.10, the error persists.
The created .dvi file appears to have all "<g" sections closed with ">".
I have a dual boot PC with Ubuntu 20.04 and TeX Live, so I can test it there too. Up to now, everything I did in MiKTeX (since 2015) also worked in TeX Live.

The log file appears okay at first glance. Here are the contents:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX 21.10) (preloaded format=latex 2021.11.25)  25 NOV 2021 18:28
entering extended mode
**./example.tex
(example.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15>
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen138
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen139

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box50
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
))
Package: pgf 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvisvgm.def on input line 107.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\dvisvgm.def
File: dvisvgm.def 2021/11/21 v1.3 dvisvgm graphics driver for latex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen140
\Gin@req@width=\dimen141
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks18
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks19

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks20
))
\pgf@x=\dimen142
\pgf@y=\dimen143
\pgf@xa=\dimen144
\pgf@ya=\dimen145
\pgf@xb=\dimen146
\pgf@yb=\dimen147
\pgf@xc=\dimen148
\pgf@yc=\dimen149
\pgf@xd=\dimen150
\pgf@yd=\dimen151
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count183
\c@pgf@countb=\count184
\c@pgf@countc=\count185
\c@pgf@countd=\count186
\t@pgf@toka=\toks21
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks22
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks23
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count187

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-dvisvgm.def

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-dvisvgm.def
File: pgfsys-dvisvgm.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys-common-svg.def
File: pgfsys-common-svg.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@sys@svg@objectcount=\count188
\pgf@sys@svg@scopecount=\count189
\pgf@sys@svg@type@count=\count190
\pgf@sys@svg@canvascount=\count191
)))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count192
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count193
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2021/10/31 v2.13 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: dvisvgm.def on input line 227.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1375.
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen152
\pgfmath@count=\count194
\pgfmath@box=\box51
\pgfmath@toks=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks25
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks26
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.co
de.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.
tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmeti
cs.code.tex)))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count195
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.tex)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen153
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen154
\pgf@picminy=\dimen155
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen156
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen157
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen158
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen159
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen160
\pgf@xx=\dimen161
\pgf@xy=\dimen162
\pgf@yx=\dimen163
\pgf@yy=\dimen164
\pgf@zx=\dimen165
\pgf@zy=\dimen166
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathconstruct.code.t
ex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen167
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen168
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen169
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen170
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfpic=\box52
\pgf@hbox=\box53
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box54
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count196
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicstate.code.te
x
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen171
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransformations.code
.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen172
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen173
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen174
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepathprocessing.code.
tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen175
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@max=\dimen176
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count197
\pgf@shadingcount=\count198
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box55
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcoretransparency.code.te
x
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box56
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen177
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen178
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen179
\pgffor@skip=\dimen180
\pgffor@stack=\toks27
\pgffor@toks=\toks28
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz\tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibraryplothandlers.code.
tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count199
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen181
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen182
\tikz@lasty=\dimen183
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen184
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen185
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen186
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen187
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen188
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen189
\tikz@figbox=\box57
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box58
\tikz@tempbox=\box59
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box60
\tikztreelevel=\count266
\tikznumberofchildren=\count267
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count268
\tikz@fig@count=\count269
 (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count270
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count271
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count272
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count273

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries\tikzlibra
rytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)
)))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-dvisvgm.def
File: l3backend-dvisvgm.def 2021-10-18 L3 backend support: dvisvgm
\g__kernel_backend_scope_int=\count274
\l__kernel_backend_scope_int=\count275
\g__box_clip_path_int=\count276
\g__draw_path_int=\count277
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box61
)
(example.aux)
\openout1 = `example.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
 [1] (example.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11318 strings out of 478682
 240806 string characters out of 2856414
 508681 words of memory out of 3000000
 29276 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 403430 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 100i,5n,104p,424b,424s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on example.dvi (1 page, 1004 bytes).
```

Comment: in texlive 2021 your example runs without error and [produces this output as svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aREcb.png)  what tex distribution are you using?

Comment: the log file reports `File: pgfsys-dvisvgm.def 2021/05/15 v3.1.9a (3.1.9a)`  what does your log say?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem here either. It seems to be an issue with the dvisvgm build of MiKTeX. I suggest to report it [there](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues) too.

Comment: I you use a shared, system-wide installation of MiKTeX, you could replace the dvisvgm binary from MiKTeX with the one available on [this website](https://dvisvgm.de/Downloads) and check if the errors go away.

Comment: I agree - it works in Ubuntu with Tex Live. The log files have too many differences to point me to something meaningful. The .dvi file is 996 bytes in Ubuntu/TeXLive and 1004 bytes in Windows/MiKTeX.

Comment: The answer is YES - the errors go away. dvisvgm.exe is 6878208 bytes on the website you mentioned and 9521152 bytes in MiKTeX - a huge difference!

Comment: can you report this to the main miktex site

Comment: @Aendie Yes, the MiKTeX build uses a lot of DLLs shared across all TeX utilities. In the separate build, all required libraries are linked statically. That's why the `.exe` file is much bigger.

Comment: Yes, I'll report this to the main MiKTeX site.

Comment: I don't understand: my case is closed as being "off-topic": https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/260

Comment: Is your system 32 or 64bit?

Comment: This is definitely a bug in the MiKTeX build of dvisvgm. I can reproduce it on my Windows machine. Unfortunately, I can't debug it, because that requires to set up a complete MiKTeX build environment with all additional libraries and stuff which I can't offer at the moment. So, the the cause of the issue should really be tracked down by the MiKTeX developers.

Comment: @vipa I've installed the 64 bit MiKTeX.

Comment: I run on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit. Thanks for your excellent responses. I will make another effort to report it to MiKTeX. I am offended by the attitude of Christian Schenk / "edocevoli" - to close an issue without a word of explanation is rude, offensive, arrogant and degrading. I compliment all of you here with kind, helpful, respectful and intelligent behavior.

Comment: I've [reported the issue](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/983) again and it has been confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Updating MikTeX solved it completely.

Excerpt from error messages before the upgrade:

```
C:\temp>dvisvgm --no-fonts svgout
pre-processing DVI file (format version 2)
processing page 1
  ERROR: error in special: '>' or '/>' expected at end of opening tag <g
  ERROR: error in special: '>' or '/>' expected at end of opening tag <g

...

  ERROR: error in special: '>' or '/>' expected at end of opening tag <g
  graphic size: 449.754997pt x 87.610598pt (158.070803mm x 30.791604mm)
  output written to svgout.svg
1 of 1 page converted in 0.123 seconds
```

The command did produce an SVG file, but components of the graphic were missing from it.

Result after the upgrade:

```
C:\temp>dvisvgm --no-fonts svgout
pre-processing DVI file (format version 2)
processing page 1
  graphic size: 449.754997pt x 94.555042pt (158.070803mm x 33.232297mm)
  output written to svgout.svg
1 of 1 page converted in 0.101 seconds
```